# How to access "two" in (("one" . "two")) in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm very new to elisp and I'm trying to adapt some existing code.

While looping over a table (generated by the orgmode function org-clock-get-table-data) I try the following:

```
((equal column "Project") (insert (cdr row)))
```

which yeilds the following in the *Messages* buffer:

```
cond: Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, (#("Verify CalTime accruals for vacation/sick" 0 41   
(fontified t org-category #("Admin" 0 5 (fontified t org-category "Admin" org-category-position 32    
line-prefix nil wrap-prefix nil ...)) org-category-position 32 line-prefix #("*" 0 1 (face org-
hide)) wrap-prefix #("    " 0 4 (face org-indent)) ...)) nil 30 (("wps" . "Administration")))
```

The value that I want to insert is "Administration" so I try this

```
((equal column "Project") (insert (nth 4 row)))
```

which yeilds the following in the minibuffer

```
Wrong type argument, char-or-string-p, (("wps" . "Administration"))
```

Can someone tell me how I can insert the string "Administration"?

**EDIT**

Thanks Wes and Drew:

```
(cdar row)
```

Doing the above yields the first element of the complex list that I saw in the *Messages* buffer earlier:

```
Verify CalTime accruals for vaction/sick
```

row seems to be a complex list of lists:

```
((equal column "Project") (insert (car row))); yeilds ^B

((equal column "Project") (insert (cdr row)))
yields:
cond: Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, (#("Verify CalTime accruals for vacation/sick" 0 41 
(fontified t org-category #("Admin" 0 5 (fontified t org-category "Admin" org-category-position 32 
line-prefix nil wrap-prefix nil ...)) org-category-position 32 line-prefix #("*" 0 1 (face org-
hide)) wrap-prefix #("    " 0 4 (face org-indent)) ...)) nil 30 (("wps" . "Administration")))
```

I think each "#" in the output above represents a list item. The fact that (nth 4 row) gives the error output shown above supports this and suggests that something like this might work:

```
((equal column "Project") (insert (nth 2 (nth 4 row))))
;yeilds wrong type argument, char-or-string-p, nil
```

So there is probably some function that I need to use to decode that 4th list item....

That 4th element is the orgmode property that has been assigned to the clocktable entry on the row we are parsing. This list of properties is defined in my .emacs:

```
(setq org-global-properties
;; WPS = Web Platform Services.  Time tracking for Google Sheet begun with CalTime Migration
            '(("wps_ALL". 
"Administration
ASG-Consulting
Chanc-Office-Website
")))
```

Comment: Confusingly, the Emacs Lisp syntax which begins `#("` in one of your snippets actually *doesn't* represent a list, but a string with text properties.  See the Info node "Text Props and Strings" in the Emacs Lisp manual for details on how it works.

Comment: For pulling apart more complex list structures, I find the `cl-destructuring-bind` and `pcase` macros to be very useful.  (The latter is only in Emacs 24).  Both let you extract parts of a list by writing down a kind of template of its structure, so the shape of the code resembles the shape of the data you are looking for.

Comment: Super-helpful!  Thanks @Jon O.  I'm trying to learn these functions.

Comment: Thanks Lisp people!  All of this info was helpful.  I chose @Phils answer because `(assoc)` was key to the solution.  For background I was adapting `org-clocktable-write-default` to flatten data so that it could be imported (CSV) to a google sheet. [Here's the key line in the diff](https://github.com/bwood/clocktable-flat/commit/160292638bd5316e069402cd4507b48510eb460a#diff-2bfaf28fc3b41857e12cdec72a082cb6R63) containing `(assoc)`. `org-clocktable-write-default` held the answer. [More code here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-06/msg01034.html) that helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that lists of the form `(("wps" . "Administration") ("foo" . "bar"))` are typically "alists", and so you *may* need to handle the situation where there is more than one item in your list.

Read: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Association Lists` <kbd>RET</kbd>
and also: `(elisp) Dotted Pair Notation`

You may obtain a keyed item from an alist with `(assoc)` or `(assq)` depending on the form of equality needed for the test. Equivalent strings are not equal *objects* in elisp, so in this case you want `assoc` rather than `assq`.

That gives you the entire `(KEY . VALUE)` form as a result, and you obtain the cdr of that as usual; hence:

```
(let ((my-alist '(("wps" . "Administration") ("foo" . "bar"))))
  (cdr (assoc "wps" my-alist)))
```

yields: "Administration"

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the `assoc` + `cdr` combination, you can also use `assoc-default`:

`ELISP> (assoc-default "one" '(("one" . "two")))
=> "two"`

Comment: Huh, I never knew of this function. Useful.

Answer (score 2):

Lists are complex to think about in elisp.  Until you've done enough of them that you stop thinking about them.  Ha ha.  But read up on the functions like `car` (picks the first element in a list) and `cdr` (picks the rest of the rest) to get started.  And then you can chain things by combining letters in short sequences at least.  So the answer you want is:

```
(cdar row)
```

Comment: To explain further: The `car` of `(("wps" . "Administration"))` is the first element of that list, `("wps" . "Administration")`. And the `cdr` of that cons is `"Administration"`.